# Kubetcl create configmap with --from-file flag, inconsistent behavior

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I'm executing create config command such as:

```
kubectl create configmap config-map-example --from-file=conf1.js=./conf-files/conf1.js --from-file=conf2.js=./conf-files/conf2.js --from-file=conf3.js=./conf-files/conf3.js --dry-run -o yaml
```

The content of each config file is either imported as string, or as block scalar, e.g:

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-map-example
apiVersion: v1
data:
  conf1.js: |-
    // conf1.js content

  conf2.js: "// conf2.js content as string with \n line breaks"

  conf3.js: |-
    // conf3.js content
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which `kubectl` version is used? In shorts words it doesn't matter, in cluster it will be stored as `key paired` value like `conf2.js` output. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1079947/626733)

Comment: No, still the same behavior, I ended up using other commands

Comment: @eitann but it doesn't work or what's the issue? Again, in kubernetes cluster it's stored in `etcd` in `json`. Output is only for human readable format with `|`. If you create configmaps, they will be in `json` since `etcd` is key-pair values storage. + Which `kubectl` version is used? Potentially they can have some difference in behaviour.